# When I upload my CodeIgniter System to my Amazon EC2, why are all of my permissions messed up?

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

For some weird reason, my "system" folder has permissions of "000" when I upload it. This totally breaks CodeIgniter as I get all sorts of errors:

```
Message: CI_Config::include(/[mysite]/system/application/config/assetlibpro.php) [ci-config.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an EC2-specific problem.  If you fix the permissions using

```
chmod -R 755 /[mysite]/system
```

you should be OK (755 means read/write/execute for owner, read/execute for group and world)